Google play billing pop up not showing free trial
I have added two subscription plan in Google play console :
1 - Monthly with offer (7 Days free trial for new user)
2 - Yearly with offer (14 days free trial for new user)
But when i click on subscribe button the billing popup not showing free trial details it is only showing subscription details.
Here is PopUp Image
I have tried creating many new users and different google ids but nothing happen.
Here is console plan preview
Is there anything i am missing.
and one more question is there any way to test free trial with one google Id intead of creating different id's for every new user.
